# Using glcolorscale with gstreamer GPU video scaling

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to find a way to do video scaling on the GPU and the only thing I could find was the glcolorscale filter. I am running streamer 1.8.0 on my ARM device and I tried to execute the following:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! "video/x-raw-yuv" | glcolorscale ! ximagesink
```

This is an example that I found in the documentation for glcolorscale but it returns an error:

```
"Could not return videotestsrc0 to glcolorscale0"
```

Comment: glcolorscale is for scaling colors not video frames.. maybe try to use glvideomixer.. but I am not sure if the scaling will happen on GPU

Comment: and you wrote caps the old way (now its just video/x-raw .. ).. and they are not necessary at all